# TypeError when using SetSizer()

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm creating a panel for a notebook, and I need to add a sizer. However, when I run my code:

```
class HomePanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        [...Widget Code...]

        self.verticalsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.verticalsizer.AddStretchSpacer(prop=1)

        self.verticalsizer.Add(self.text, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.BOTTOM, border=30)
        self.verticalsizer.Add(self.text1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.BOTTOM, border=20)

        self.verticalsizer.AddStretchSpacer(prop=1)

        HomePanel.SetSizer(self.verticalsizer)
        HomePanel.Layout()
```

I get a typeerror regarding line the SetSizer():

```
TypeError: unbound method SetSizer() must be called with HomePanel instance as first argument (got BoxSizer instance instead)
```

I'm not sure what else I could assign the SetSizer() to, but since this won't work either I'm stuck. Is there a way to get around this or do it better?

Comment: Why are you trying to call instance methods using the class? Why not just do `self.SetSizer(self.verticalsizer); self.Layout()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
        HomePanel.SetSizer(self.verticalsizer)
        HomePanel.Layout()
```

Use self:

```
        self.SetSizer(self.verticalsizer)
        self.Layout()
```

Comment: Thanks -- bit of a wxpython noob as you can see.